# Windows AppFabric: Host unable to impersonate with SQL Server backing store

Tags: appfabric

Have a two host AppFabric setup. Both hosts are Win2k8 standard and are running the 32 bit version of AppFabric. The entire system has a backing SQL server store that has the AppFabric database store. Connectivity is not an issue between the systems, verified independently.

When I start the cache-cluster I get this error:

(AppFabric Caching service crashed with exception {Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ConfigStoreException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON')

It appears that AppFabric is unable to impersonate the user it is running / configured with into SQL server. We have configured accounts for the domain user that will run AppFabric, also accounts for the machines. Any help is appreciated, we've been stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: should point out that SQL server SPN has come up as a potential solution but its not conclusive that its due to a missing SPN entry. This article is somewhat on topic : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/windows-server-appfabric-troubleshooting-anonymous-logon.aspx

Comment: After working with Microsoft and checking every possible outcome, it turns out that AppFabric requires SPN to be setup on the AD environment. For whatever reason the NTLM authentication wasn't sticking. It's still puzzling, but adding an SPN entry for the SQL server did the trick. Don't have an explanation yet - but atleast there is a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably checking things you've already been through but let's see if we can rule a few things out first.

Can you confirm that:

- the domain account isn't locked out for some reason, has a non-expiring password etc
- the AppFabric Caching service is configured (on both servers) in the Services Control Panel applet to run under the domain account you've created
- the domain account has access to SQL Server *and* the AppFabric config database

Can you start either cache server individually?

Comment: Phil, thanks. Yes, have done all this. Domain a/c is not locked (am logged in with that account), The service is configured to run with network service (which is the recommended default set by the config tool) - for fun, we tried to run it as the named domain user, but that needs a ton of other security policy settings. The domain account has access to the SQL server and the database.  The problem is : the service wont start, because it cant impersonate into the database. Have checked all this.

Answer (score 0):

Domain Account Configuration is not supported in V1.0. Only Network Service can be configured in V1.0.

Comment: Shalabh : the AppFabric service is configured to run as Network Service. I'm not trying to run the service as a named domain user. The AppFabric install was done by logging into the servers using the same domain user. As I understand it, the service is set to run as network service, but when it actually runs, it tries to impersonate the user that was used to install the software on the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I have understood the problem correctly.
Configuration: AppFabric 1.0 installed with SQL server config store. All other default configurations. 
Symptom: Service does not start on the machines due to sql server connection error.
If the above is correct, you can try the following:
Issue: The AppFabric Service runs as network service on the server mahcines for security reasons. When the service tries to access the sql server config store, it sees a permission issue. 
Resolution: Give permission for the NT service / Machine$ account for all the server nodes on the sql server for the config store db. 
Let us know if this solves the issue.

Comment: Rohit - the Machine$ accounts have been created on the SQL server for each host that is part of the cluster. This already exists. There was one deviation from standard install - where we created our own configuration database and users/perms using our own scripts - am going to try the stock out of the box configuration option - although I'm not very hopeful, since our scripts did exactly what the installer did.